# I want to use defer with Scripts.Render and preload with Styles.Render

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use `defer` with Scripts.Render and `preload` with Styles.Render, I have used some formats but my problem is not solved.

I am sharing the formats which I have used below.

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' defer></script>","~/bundles/jquery")

<script src="@(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery"))" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This breaks CDN fallback using CDN Fallback Expression. The fallback check will be executed before the deferred script is loading causing the fallback to always kick in.